# Console Google oAuth - Verification

Tags: console-application

Three months ago I create my app on https://console.developers.google.com/

I still waiting for verification. Do anyone know how long is verification process?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related, contact customer support.

Comment: I have the same problem - I'm waiting for verification 3 month already. I didn't find any channel to connect to google except this community. 
@ManovTools Ltd. did you application became verified?